# e.UserState is null in BackgroundWorker progressChanged event with multiple ReportProgress calls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is the method of downloading file for the ftp server:
In the download method when i'm doing:

```
var progress = bytesRead * 100.0 / writeStream.Length;
bw.ReportProgress((int)progress);
```

Thne for some reason in form1 in the progressChanged event the e.UserState is null even that i have the reporting:

```
string SummaryText = String.Format("File Name {0} / {1}", "", filenameonly);
bw.ReportProgress(0, SummaryText);
```

Without the second reporting then the e.UserState is working fine.

```
public void DownloadFtpContent(object sender ,string file, string filesdirectories,string fn)
{    
    try
    {     
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        string filenameonly = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string ftpdirectories = Path.Combine(ftpcontentdir, filesdirectories);
        string fileurl = "ftp://" + file;
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;                
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fileurl);                                
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;                
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;                 
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        if (!Directory.Exists(ftpdirectories))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(ftpdirectories);
        }
        FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly, FileMode.Create);
        string fnn = ftpdirectories + "\\" + filenameonly;
        int Length = 2048;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        string SummaryText = String.Format("File Name {0} / {1}", "", filenameonly);
        bw.ReportProgress(0, SummaryText);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
            var progress = bytesRead * 100.0 / writeStream.Length;
            bw.ReportProgress((int)progress);
        }               
        writeStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException wEx)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(wEx.Message, "Download Error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Download Error");
    }
}
```

In form1 in the progressChanged event when i'm using the e.UserState i'm getting exception say it's null:

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
    this.toolStripProgressBar2.Value = Math.Min(this.toolStripProgressBar2.Maximum, e.ProgressPercentage);
}
```

The first time was ok but the second time it's getting to the ProgressChanged and trying to make the e.UserState line i'm getting the exception.

The exception is:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=FTP_ProgressBar
  StackTrace:
       at FTP_ProgressBar.Form1.backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(Object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\Form1.cs:line 566
  InnerException:
```

line 566 is: this.toolStripStatusLabel2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();

Comment: You aren't always passing a state: `bw.ReportProgress((int)progress);`

Comment: It was my mistake i changed so the report is only inside the while loop and there only there i also reporting the SummaryText variable so now it's working fine . But i have another problem i'm not sure if to describe it here or to make a new question since all the information is already here.

Comment: @HorheElFenenado Always make a new question.

Comment: I rolled it back to the original question.  Either delete it or post your answer as an answer.  The downvotes are probably coming from the lousy title.

Comment: juharr i can't i got blocked.

Comment: Oops i didn't notice for the title. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by reporting only once in the download method in the while loop:

```
string SummaryText = String.Format("File Name {0} / {1}", "", filenameonly);
while (bytesRead > 0)
{
    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
    var progress = bytesRead * 100.0 / writeStream.Length;
    bw.ReportProgress((int)progress, SummaryText);
}
```